# When navigating back in navigation controller view doesn't load

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have weird situation and have no clue how to debug it. I load three viewControllers in navigation controller. When Im navigating back from there second and first ViewController doesn't display anything just white screen I added print methods everywhere in lifecycle methods and it seems that it loads views but anyway they not visible. What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you, please, attach code?

Comment: How you call new ViewController and navigate back from it?

Comment: Maybe you are not pushing the view controllers properly and because of that when you get back you are getting a blank screens

Answer (score 0):

Yep It's weird, There maybe some code which do something with your view on such events like:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    // remove some subviews or change constraints.
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    // remove some subviews or change constraints.

}
```

Please send us a code of the view controller which has the problems and code how exactly you show the controller.